# How to set the KafkaHeaders.MESSAGE_KEY in spring integration

Tags: java, spring, apache-kafka, spring-integration

Can someone please help me with setting random `KafkaHeaders.MESSAGE_KEY` for below code so that I can publish the payload into different partitions.

```
@Bean
public IntegrationFlow fileInboundChannelFlow() {
    FileInboundChannelAdapterSpec messageSourceSpec = Files
            .inboundAdapter(Paths.get(this.properties.getDirectory()).toFile());

    messageSourceSpec = messageSourceSpec.filter(getFilter());
    //messageSourceSpec.regexFilter(this.properties.getFilenameRegex());
    messageSourceSpec.preventDuplicates(this.properties.isPreventDuplicates());

    IntegrationFlowBuilder flowBuilder = IntegrationFlows.from(messageSourceSpec)
            .split(new FileSplitter(true, true))
            .enrichHeaders(h -> h.header(KafkaHeaders.MESSAGE_KEY, "payload.flightNumber"));

    return flowBuilder.<Object, Class<?>>route(Object::getClass,
            m -> m.channelMapping(FileSplitter.FileMarker.class, "markers.input").channelMapping(String.class,
                    "lines.input"))
            .get();
}
```

I want to set key based on payload.prod_cd.
As it is singleton bean i want to initialize different kafka header key for each payload.

Answer (score 2):

You are on the right track with that:

```
.enrichHeaders(h -> h.header(KafkaHeaders.MESSAGE_KEY, "payload.flightNumber"));
```

Only what you need is to use a `headerExpression()` instead:

```
/**
 * Add a single header specification where the value is a String representation of a
 * SpEL {@link Expression}. If the header exists, it will <b>not</b> be overwritten
 * unless {@link #defaultOverwrite(boolean)} is true.
 * @param name the header name.
 * @param expression the expression.
 * @return the header enricher spec.
 */
public HeaderEnricherSpec headerExpression(String name, String expression) {
```

Comment: Hello I have changed the file  .enrichHeaders(h -> h.headerExpression(KafkaHeaders.MESSAGE_KEY,"T(java.util.UUID).randomUUID().toString()")); but each file is having different key not the each record in file

Comment: Such an `enrichHeaders()` operator must be after `.split(new FileSplitter(true, true))`. Then each record from the file is going to have its own `KafkaHeaders.MESSAGE_KEY`. Note: for that `UUID` variant you can consider to use a `headerFunction()` instead for convenience and code completion.